# Give feedback after submitted answer using button onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am new at js. I have learned how to create a button to submit an answer. But I would like now to give feedback to the user depending on they answer. I have tried this.

```
<h1>What is your choice?</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Cooperate"> Cooperate
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Betray"> Betray
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer(d1.choice.value)">Submit Answer</button>
<script>
var submitAnswer = function() {

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('choice');
  var val= "";
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
  if (val == "Cooperate" ) {
    alert('3 points');
  } else if {val == "Betray"
    alert('0 points');
  }
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
 function submitAnswer(){
   var selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;
      if (selected === "Cooperate"){
        alert("3");
      }else{
        alert("0");
      }
  }
```

```html
<h1>What is your choice?</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Cooperate"> Cooperate
   <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Betray"> Betray
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have many errors in your code,
it should look simply like this:

```
<h1>What is your choice?</h1><br>
<form id="d1">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Cooperate"> Cooperate
   <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Betray"> Betray
</form>
<button onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
<script>
  var submitAnswer = function() {

      var selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;

      if (selected)
        alert(selected);
      }

  };

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to assign a different value to each answer though. For example, if cooperate you get 3 points, if not 0 points.